# Render another root path with own routes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to figure render a complete seperate admin path with its own routes.

Is it possible to render say admin page that is with and existing project.

At the moment I have the following code it is working very well.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './client/App.js';
import Admin from './admin/admin.js';

var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if (pathname.substring(0, 6) == '/admin') {
  ReactDOM.render(<Admin />, document.getElementById('root'));
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

Comment: you should use routing library for this use case, the way you’re doing things right now is unsustainable for a real world project. check out react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to understand what you want to do exactly. You already have everything you need, Admin and App are components and therefore small *projects* I would say. However, you *shouldn't* do it that way and instead use [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) it avoids you to check the window location pathname by yourself and will save you a lof of time and headache.

Comment: [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13490294/matt-gimel), please accept this as answer if it helped you.